# How to vertically center Wordpress navigation bar

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have a navigation bar at following wordpress site: http://tarjom.ir/demo/pwp

I have two major issues with this navigation bar:

1- I can't vertically align it at the middle.

2- There is a `div` wrapper as the parent of the `<ul>` tag that I can't remove it. However I have already set `'container' => ''`, but it does not work.

```
<!-- Navigation bar-->
  <div id='wp_nav_section' class='grid-100 black-gray-bg font-roya' style='min-height: 100px; display: block;height:100%;'>
    <?php wp_nav_menu(array("container" => 'nav')); ?> 
  </div>
<!-- End of navigation bar. -->
```

Here is my wordpress navigation code:

Here is all my CSS related to the wordpress navigation:

```
.menu
    {
        height: 65px;
        min-height: 60px;   
        padding: 0px;
        text-align: right;
        background-color: #111;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
.menu ul
    {
     direction: rtl;
     width: 70%;
     margin-right: auto;
     margin-left: auto;
     overflow: hidden;
     height: auto;
     padding-top: 0px;
    }
.menu li
    { 
      padding: 0px 0px;
      display: inline-block; 
    }
    .menu li a
    {
      color: white;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block ;
      height: 45px;
      background-color: black; 
      border-right: 2px #333 solid; 
      padding: 16px 7% 3px 3%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      width: 100px;
      margin: 0px 0px;
      font-size: 110%;
    }
    .menu li a:hover
    {
        background-color: #333;
        border-right: 2px #F90 solid;
    }
```

I need the `<ul>` tag to be centered vertically in the `<div>` wrapper.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove height from `.menu{}` class. this will solved your vertical align issue.

Comment: thanks your solution worker perfectly. but do you have any idea why it sucks in chrome? could your please take a look at it in chrome?

Comment: oh mine used a chached page. thank it's ok. only needs a little workaround in chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I would try this, if you haven't already:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( 
array ( 
'container' =>false,
'items_wrap' => '%3$s', //"%3$s" is the li list itself. See below for the default value.
 ) ); ?>
```

The default values for these two parameters are:

```
'container'       => 'div',
'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
```

So I would make sure to define those the way you want them in your call to wp_nav_menu().

You can read more info on my post at http://icode4you.net/wordpress-tricks-customizing-the-output-of-wp_nav_menu/

To center the UL within a div, I would use this code:

```
<style>
div {
text-align:center;
}

ul {
display:inline-block;
}

</style>
```

Let me know if you would like any more information or help :)